# TagHelper to supress Razor processing

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Is there a possibility to write a tag helper which tells Razor not to process it's content. 
I would like to define new `<raw>` tag and everything between opening and closing "raw" tag should go to result HTML "as is".
For example, the following markup:

```
<raw>
  Some text. 
  @Something
  <some-other-tag-helper />
<raw>
```

Should go to result HTML exactly as it's listed between `<raw>` and `</raw>` without trying to consider @Something as a variable or "unpacking" other tag helpers.

Comment: Razor defines a `<text>` tag that already does something like this. Does that help in your case?

Comment: Hm. I didn't think of <text> tag as a possible solution. 
I will definitely try it. Thanks!